# Ubuntu 18.04 "Bootup is not yet finished. Please try again later." error

Tags: boot, 18.04

My Ubuntu 18.04 takes too long to boot up (about minute or so). I found that it's possible to find out the reason using `systemd-analyze`, but all it gives me is `Bootup is not yet finished. Please try again later.` The system runs normally, but even after hour and more, the boot up is still not finished. Is there a way to find out what is not loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: 
systemctl list-jobs
From:
https://www.horizonemb.com/tech-blog-posts/handling-systemd-analyze-error-bootup-is-not-yet-finished/

> **Overview**
>
> The systemd-analyze tool requires that all boot services are completed
>   before the tool can be run successfully. If there are still
>   outstanding services active, then the following error will be
>   returned:
>
> ```
> root@yocto-platform1:~# systemd-analyze    
> Bootup is not yet finished. Please try again later.
> ```
>
> **Diagnosing**
>
> To find out what services are still active, the systemctl list-jobs
>   command can be used, e.g.:
>
> ```
> root@yocto-platform1:~# systemctl list-jobs   
> JOB UNIT TYPE STATE   
> 1 multi-user.target start waiting   
> 102 rsync-appdatas.service start running  
> 82 sync-rtc-to-sys-clock.service start running  
> 83 systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service start waiting 4 jobs listed.
> ```
>
> These services can then be stopped as required:
>
> ````
> root@yocto-platform1:~# systemctl stop rsync-appdatas ```
> ````
>
> **Causes**
>
> A service which has not compete at start-up will need to be
>   investigated. Once possible cause the the misconfiguration of a custom
>   service which is started at boot time, and is expected to behave as a
>   traditional Unix daemon by running continuously after boot has
>   completed. For these types of services they should be configured as
>   Type=forking. See here for further details (don’t forget to add the
>   creation of a PIDFile):
>   https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html